# How to set button + vertical center with input element?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I have

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="description">Diễn giải</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;" id="description" name="description" value=""></td>
    <td><label for="accountObjectGroupListName" id="accountObjectGroupListName_label">Nhóm KH, NCC</label></td>
    <td>
        <div style="width: 87%; display: inline-block;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_accountObjectGroupListName" value="1"><div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-multiselect-clearable" unselectable="on" title="" style=""><div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" role="listbox" unselectable="on"><ul unselectable="on" class="k-reset" id="accountObjectGroupListName_taglist"></ul><input class="k-input k-readonly" style="width: 241px;" accesskey="" autocomplete="off" role="listbox" title="" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-autocomplete="list" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="accountObjectGroupListName_taglist" aria-labelledby="accountObjectGroupListName_label" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span><span class="k-icon k-i-loading k-hidden"></span></div><select multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Chọn nhóm Đối tượng kế toán" id="accountObjectGroupListName" name="accountObjectGroupListName" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;"><option value="1">KH_LE</option><option value="2">DL</option><option value="3">DLC1</option><option value="4">KH_DA</option><option value="5">DLC2</option><option value="6">NCC_HH</option><option value="7">NCC_DV</option></select><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 26.4px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: -3333px; left: -3333px;">Chọn nhóm Đối tượng kế toán</span></div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#accountObjectGroupListName").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
                });
            </script>                    
        </div>&nbsp;<a class="k-button k-primary" href="/add_account_object_group" title="Thêm Nhóm KH, NCC" style="display: inline-table;"><span class="k-icon k-i-add" style="color: gold;"></span></a>            
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It works! Please post your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```